# Maximum call stack size exceeded on GraphQL Upload with NestJS

Tags: graphql, upload, nestjs

I'm facing an error on file upload with GraphQL Upload using the ReadStream function:

```
error: 17:10:32.466+02:00 [ExceptionsHandler] Maximum call stack size exceeded
error: 17:10:32.467+02:00 [graphql] Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at ReadStream.open (/Users/xxxx/Documents/Xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx-api/node_modules/fs-capacitor/lib/index.js:80:7)
    at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:117:12)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/fs/streams.js:110:3)
    at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:96:15)
    at ReadStream.open (/Users/xxxx/Documents/Xxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx-api/node_modules/fs-capacitor/lib/index.js:90:11)
    at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:117:12)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/fs/streams.js:110:3)
    at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:96:15)
    at ReadStream.open (/Users/xxxx/Documents/Xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx-api/node_modules/fs-capacitor/lib/index.js:90:11)
    at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:117:12) {"stack":"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded\n    at ReadStream.open (/Users/xxxx/Documents/Xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx-api/node_modules/fs-capacitor/lib/index.js:80:7)\n    at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:117:12)\n    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/fs/streams.js:110:3)\n    at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:96:15)\n    at ReadStream.open (/Users/xxxxx/Documents/Xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx-api/node_modules/fs-capacitor/lib/index.js:90:11)\n    at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:117:12)\n    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (internal/fs/streams.js:110:3)\n    at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:96:15)\n    at ReadStream.open (/Users/xxxx/Documents/Xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx-api/node_modules/fs-capacitor/lib/index.js:90:11)\n    at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:117:12)"}
(node:44569) [DEP0135] DeprecationWarning: ReadStream.prototype.open() is deprecated
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Here is the function I'm using to upload a file:

```js
public async cleanUpload(upload: GraphqlUpload, oldName?: string) {
    let uploadResponse: FileInfo;
    try {
      if (oldName) {
        this.safeRemove(oldName);
      }
      uploadResponse = await this.uploadFile(
        {
          fileName: upload.filename,
          stream: upload.createReadStream(),
          mimetype: upload.mimetype,
        },
        { isPublic: true, filter: imageFilterFunction },
      );
      return uploadResponse;
    } catch (e) {
      this.logger.error('unable to upload', e);
      if (uploadResponse) {
        this.safeRemove(uploadResponse.fileName);
      }
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to downgrade the **Node version** to **12.18** from **14.17**.

Answer (score 0):

To keep using Node 14.17 what you can do is to disable Apollo's internal upload and use [graphql-upload](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload)

Please see [this comment](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/901#issuecomment-780007582) which outline the approach quoted here.

> For any future readers, here is how to fix the issue once and for all.
>
> The problem is that @nestjs/graphql's dependency, apollo-server-core, depends on an old version of graphql-upload (v8.0) which has conflicts with newer versions of Node.js and various packages. Apollo Server v2.21.0 [seems to have fixed this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v2210) but @nestjs/graphql is still on v2.16.1. Furthermore, Apollo Server v3 will be [removing the built-in graphql-upload](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3508#issuecomment-777792243).
>
> The solution [suggested in this comment](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3508#issuecomment-732261211) is to disable Apollo Server's built-in handling of uploads and use your own. This can be done in 3 simple steps:
>
> ##### 1. package.json
>
> Remove the fs-capacitor and graphql-upload entries from the resolutions section if you added them, and install the latest version of graphql-upload (v11.0.0 at this time) package as a dependency.
>
> ##### 2. src/app.module.ts
>
> Disable Apollo Server's built-in upload handling and add the graphqlUploadExpress middleware to your application.
>
> ```js
> import { graphqlUploadExpress } from "graphql-upload"
> import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from "@nestjs/common"
>
> @Module({
>   imports: [
>     GraphQLModule.forRoot({
>       uploads: false, // disable built-in upload handling
>     }),
>   ],
> })
> export class AppModule implements NestModule {
>   configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
>     consumer.apply(graphqlUploadExpress()).forRoutes("graphql")
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ##### 3. src/blog/post.resolver.ts (example resolver)
>
> Remove the GraphQLUpload import from apollo-server-core and import from graphql-upload instead
>
> ```js
> // import { GraphQLUpload } from "apollo-server-core" <-- remove this
> import { FileUpload, GraphQLUpload } from "graphql-upload"
>
> @Mutation(() => Post)
> async postCreate(
>   @Args("title") title: string,
>   @Args("body") body: string,
>   @Args("attachment", { type: () => GraphQLUpload }) attachment: Promise<FileUpload>,
> ) {
>   const { filename, mimetype, encoding, createReadStream } = await attachment
>   console.log("attachment:", filename, mimetype, encoding)
>
>   const stream = createReadStream()
>   stream.on("data", (chunk: Buffer) => /* do stuff with data here */)
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm already using GraphQL Upload in this case.

Comment: Have you disabled apollo's internal upload ? the instruction i have quoted and linked would allow you to use node 14 without downgrading to node 12. i have used it on a project of mine on node 14